# Custom PHP CAPTCHA

Tags: php, captcha

ive written a php function that displays a random equation.  if the correct answer is not provided, the submission fails.  the equation is like so:

[ random digit or text number ]  [ randomly selects +,-,x ]  [ random digit or text number ]= ?

so you might see:
8+2=?, or seven - 4 = ?, etc

ive tested this manually and it seems to work beautifully.  i cannot get around answering the CAPTCHA correctly.  yet something or someone IS posting spam despite this CAPTCHA.  ***so my question is, are there programs out there that can solve this problem?***

here is my form:

```
<form action="scripts/handler_post.php" method="post" id="gb_form">
                    <h3>Leave us a comment:</h3><br />
                    <div id="form_msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="Your Name" />
                    <textarea name="message">Your Message</textarea>

                    <?php include('includes/bmw_captcha.php'); ?> 
                    <div style="color:red; font-size:90%;">*What does <?php echo $array_num1[1] . " " . $array_calculation[0] . " " . $array_num2[1] . " = "; ?>    
                    <input type='text' maxlength='2' name='captcha' style="color:#640513; width:25px;" />?</div>
                    <div><span style="font:italic 90% Arial; color:#666;">(For security purposes, please answer this CAPTCHA problem.)</span></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="captcha_answer" value="<?php echo $array_calculation[1]; ?>" />

                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Post" />
                </form>
```

here is the script that handles the form:

```
// submitted values
$name       = clean_string( $_POST['name'] );
$message    = clean_string( $_POST['message'] );
$captcha    = clean_string( $_POST['captcha'] );
$captcha_ans= clean_string( $_POST['captcha_answer'] );

// check if name var is empty or contains digits
if( empty($name) || (strcspn( $name, '0123456789' ) != strlen( $name )) ) 
{ header( 'Location: /guestbook.php?msg=n' ); }

else if( empty($message) )
{ header( 'Location: /guestbook.php?msg=m' ); }

else if( empty($captcha) || $captcha != $captcha_ans )
{ header( 'Location: /guestbook.php?msg=cap' ); }

else 
{
    $query = "
            INSERT INTO $table_posts ( id, name, message, timestamp ) 
            VALUES( 0, \"$name\", \"$message\", now() )
    ";

    $result = $db_connect->query( $query ); // execute the query

    if( $result )
    {       
        header('Location: ../guestbook.php?msg=1');
    }

    else
        header('Location: ../guestbook.php?msg=2');
}
```

Comment: Is the answer in the form too? If so it wouldn't be hard to alter that hidden field

Comment: You can try this: http://captchas.net/sample/php/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the answer to the captcha in a session variable instead. Sending it in clear text through the form makes it possible for a robot to just set the field to whatever value it wants. Bots are usually setting all unknown fields to some string, like *ijhsg87dfb34* so if it sets both the `captcha` and the `captcha_answer` field to the same value it will succeed!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach is to use a hidden field, and in the script that handles the POST you check if that field was filled in, if it was then it was a BOT etc as a normal user would never see that field but BOTs etc just blindly fill in every field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try non-captcha secure form. Check this 
[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Safer_Contact_Forms_Without_CAPTCHAs](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aSafer_Contact_Forms_Without_CAPTCHAs)